# Sending mail on a linux machine

Tags: email

In what ways can mail be sent? I am familiar with cron mail and php sending mail, but does a mail MTA such as postfix or sendmail need to be installed on the server? Is php also a mta? What if sendmail/postfix isn't installed?

I'm also curious about how web forms with emails send registration emails out to people. I suppose it could be php's 'mail' function or something else.

Comment: PHP scripts can both use an SMTP server (such as a local MTA) or send the mail directly. It depends on the script.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not an MTA. By default, `mail()` uses the local MTA, but you can configure PHP to use a remote MTA over SMTP, if none exists on the local machine.

Most web forms use `mail()` to send email, as might be expected; there are lots of message construction libraries out there, but they all pretty much boil down to `mail()` underneath.